# Solution to Excerpt Customisation with new Gutenberg Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have made several customisations to the native Wordpress Excerpt metabox which no longer seem to work with the new Gutenberg editor and I can find no documentation online that guides me to a solution.

Does anyone know how the following code snippets can be amended to work with the new Gutenberg Editor?

This snippet removes the native Excerpt and repositions it at the top of the Editor screen below the Title metabox:

```
function remove_normal_excerpt() {
remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt' , 'post' , 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_normal_excerpt' );

function add_new_excerpt_meta( $post_type ) {
$post_types = get_post_types( array ( 'public' => true ) );
$excluded_posttypes = array ();
$post_type = array_diff($post_types, $excluded_posttypes);
add_meta_box(
'postexcerpt',
__( 'Excerpt', '' ),
'post_excerpt_meta_box',
$post_type,
'advanced',
'high', 0, 0
);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_new_excerpt_meta' );
```

This snippet adds an information notice to the Excerpt metabox:

```
function excerpt_add_notice( $translation, $original ) {
if ( 'Excerpt' == $original ) {
return 'Excerpt';
}else{
$pos = strpos($original, 'Excerpts are optional hand-crafted summaries of             
your');
if ($pos !== false) {
return  '<h5 class="notice notice info">Always complete your excerpt     
sections.</h5>';
}
}
return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'excerpt_add_notice', 10, 2 );
```

This snippet adds a javascript character count limit to the Excerpt:

```
function excerpt_count_js(){
global $post;
if ( get_post_type($post) != 'storefront' ) {
echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div         
style=\"position:absolute;top:12px;right:34px;color:#666;\"><small>Excerpt     
length: </small><span id=\"excerpt_counter\"></span><span style=\"font-
weight:bold; padding-left:7px;\">/ 170</span><small><span style=\"font-    
weight:bold; padding-left:7px;\">character(s).</span></small></div>");
jQuery("span#excerpt_counter").text(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
jQuery("#excerpt").keyup( function() {
if(jQuery(this).val().length > 170){
jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().substr(0, 170));
}
jQuery("span#excerpt_counter").text(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
});
});</script>';
}
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
```

Is it just a case of something simple as the Excerpt metabox identifiers having been changed?

Comment: Have you tried reverting to the classic editor to fix your problem? Or do you need it to be Gutenberg?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply. Yes, I've currently set things up so that the Classic Editor is used in order to ensure the above functionality works. There is a Classic Editor plugin available from Wordpress that does this. However, I would like to be able to make things compatible with the new Gutenberg editor if possible.